# How to automatically merge two Excel Worksheets with the Same First Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, merge

Before anyone states that this problem has already been answered before, I am looking for a **automatic** (macro, program, etc) system that can achieve the following:

- Merge multiple workbooks (separate files, not sheets) by a common column.

The first column is the same for all the files. However, there are **500 individual csv files**, each with about **7000 rows**

I am aware of the VLOOKUP() function, the Consolidate function, and programs like Kutools and Ablebits. However, none of these seem to suit my purpose of creating a single workbook with all of these files combined by the common column.

Does anyone know of a VBA macro or other program that can assist me with this?

EDIT: Below are links to two of the 500 files:

1.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rRdNS9K6QYjfH2_P9wmR5YS0-Ectl1SnVn2SfFz9UUY/edit?usp=sharing

2.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Dmc6hKHCG4RBF2an3NZ7nux5ffI5F5cigbz5fFyaPI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How many columns does your csv files have? Can you provide a sample of your data? Is a python solution acceptable (a dozen lines of python + pandas should do the trick...)?

Comment: Python is perfectly fine! Each .csv file only has two columns.

Comment: So the output should be a csv file with ~7000 rows and ~500+1 columns?

Comment: Precisely. Also, I have edited the original post to include two of the 500 files. As you can see, the first columns of each file are identical.

Answer (score 0):

On a [Linux shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), combine [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) and [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk).

`paste -d , *.csv | awk -F , '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) $i=""} {print}'`

The paste command puts all columns of all files next to each other. The awk script deletes all odd columns, starting with the third one.

Comment: I followed the instructions and downloaded Ubuntu on my computer. I ran the shell and moved the directory (cd command) to the file of interest. However, when I ran the command you posted, i get the following error:

paste: '*.csv': No such file or directory

I did an ls command to make sure, and all my csv files are there.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed the issue. All my file extensions were shown as .CSV, not .csv. The command is case sensitive to the file extension. My final question: Where is the new file now? The command ran perfectly, but I don't see a new file.

Comment: The output is shown in the console. Redirect it to a file by adding ` > output.txt` to write it to the file `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to have it in a CSV file. The ultimate goal is to have a .csv (or xlsx) file that will have the approximately 7000 columns and 500 rows (one for each of the files' second columns). I redirecting the command to a csv file, but it didn't work properly, and only showed a large single column.

Comment: @koreamaniac101 - you can use any valid filename for output with a redirect. So instead of `output.txt`, use `myfile.csv` or similar.